# Android Recyclerview show hide checkbox on click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, visibility

I am handling an onclick listener in a recycler view using an interface. In the on onBindViewHolder I am checking if a boolean value is true or false determine if the checkbox needs to be shown or not.

```
if(show){
checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
checkBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

but on changing the boolean value the view visibility is not changed as the onBindView is not called. How do I call the onBindView or refresh the items so that the visibility is reflected on the items.

Here is the adapter code:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExpenseVH expenseVH, int i) {
    ExpenseListModel model = arrayList.get(i);
        Log.i(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: "+ showCheck);
        expenseVH.date.setText(model.getDate());
        expenseVH.vendor.setText(model.getVendor());
        expenseVH.center.setText(model.getCenter());
        expenseVH.item.setText(model.getItem());
        expenseVH.app_amt.setText(String.format("%s %s", context.getResources().getString(R.string.Rs),model.getApp_amt()));
        expenseVH.amount.setText(String.format("%s %s", context.getResources().getString(R.string.Rs), model.getAmount()));
        expenseVH.sl.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1).concat("."));
        if(showCheck){
            expenseVH.checkBox.setClickable(true);
            expenseVH.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            expenseVH.checkBox.setClickable(false);
            expenseVH.checkBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
```

The adapter is taking the context,an arraylist, a onclick interface and the boolean value to toggle the visibility

```
ExpenseAdapter adapter = new ExpenseAdapter(this,arraylist,pos ->{
if(value){
showCheck = true;
}else{
showCheck = false;
}
},showCheck);
```

here the pos is the onclick listener I am using java 1.8 hence the lambda syntax and the `show` after that is the boolean value. This is not working at the moment.

Comment: Can you show your adapter code please

Comment: yes I will add it now

Comment: show your adapter code

Comment: `showCheck` depends on what?

Comment: From where are you getting `showCheck` Thingy.

Comment: Use DataBinding to achieve this effectively

Comment: @UmangBurman its from the activity using the adapter...I have changed the variable name please see it again

Comment: @Debu can you give me an example

Comment: Are you getting anything at this line: `Log.i(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: "+ showCheck);` on your logcat?

Comment: Please display your full adapter class.

Comment: I do something like this with list view but I put a variable in my model so if it is checked or not. I think get that from your model and it will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
if(show)
{
    show== false;
    checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else
{
    show==true;
    checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: this is ok but when I am updating the boolean value of `show` on click, the visiblity of the checkboxes are not updated without scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to add a boolean field named isSelected in model object passing to recyclerview. The initial value of isSelected shall be false. Then in onBindViewHolder() add yourCheckbox.setChecked(isSelected).Initially, all checkboxes will be unselected since we have initialized isSelected with false.

The important part is to listen to onClick event for the checkbox or the entire view containing checkbox. If the checkbox is selected, then set the isSelected = true, else false.
Don't forget to call notifyDataSetChanged() on yourCheckbox clicked/checked event.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain any state,add one additional property in your Model like below

```
class ExpenseListModel{

public boolean show;


}
```

Then use in your onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExpenseVH expenseVH, int i) {
    ExpenseListModel model = arrayList.get(i);
        Log.i(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: "+ showCheck);
        expenseVH.date.setText(model.getDate());
        expenseVH.vendor.setText(model.getVendor());
        expenseVH.center.setText(model.getCenter());
        expenseVH.item.setText(model.getItem());
        expenseVH.app_amt.setText(String.format("%s %s", context.getResources().getString(R.string.Rs),model.getApp_amt()));
        expenseVH.amount.setText(String.format("%s %s", context.getResources().getString(R.string.Rs), model.getAmount()));
        expenseVH.sl.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1).concat("."));
        expenseVH.checkBox.setClickable(model.show ? true : false);
        expenseVH.checkBox.setVisibility(model.show ? View.VISIBLE : VIEW.INVISIBLE);

        }
```

If you want to change the status, then update in your onclickListener and call `notifyItemChanged(position)`